# Limit Question (Calculus 2)

Tags: calculus, limits

Simply put, is there a way to show that $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$$

where $$a_n = \frac {(n^2-n)^{1+1/n}}{(1+\frac {1}{n})^\sqrt{(n^2-n)}}$$

This is a problem I may incorporate into a project for AP Calculus BC/Calculus 2, so using methods with that skill level in mind is preferable (if not possible, I will still appreciate a proof nonetheless).

The most progress I've made was through taking the natural logarithm and using those properties to arrive at $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} ln\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)\ln\left(n^2+n\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sqrt{n^2-n}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln(n^2-n)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\sqrt{n^2+n}\right]$$

and although I can deal with the first and third terms using L'Hôpital's Rule, I was unable to finish off the second and fourth terms.

(Also, apologies if anything seemed confusing in the equations. I'm new to MathJax and the website in general).

Thank you kindly!

Comment: You're doing well with the MathJax!

Comment: Are you in fact calculating $\ln [ a_{n+1}/a_n]$ here, then hoping to show that log goes to zero as $n \to \infty$? (In your writeup you dropped the initial $\ln$) Also the whole thing should start out $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ rather than $x \to \infty.$

Comment: That's right; thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting $\sqrt {n^2-n} = n\sqrt {1-1/n},$ we have

$$ \frac{a_n}{n^2/e} = \frac{n^2-n}{n^2}\cdot \frac{e}{[(1+1/n)^n]^{\sqrt {1-1/n}} }\cdot(n^2-n)^{1/n}.$$

The first fraction on the right $\to 1.$ In the second fraction, the term in brackets in the denominator $\to e,$ and the power $\sqrt {1-1/n}\to 1.$ So the full denominator $\to e^1 = e.$ Hence the second fraction $\to 1.$ For the last term we have $1\le n^2-n \le n^2$ for $n>1.$ Hence $1\le (n^2-1)^{1/n}\le (n^2)^{1/n}$ $ = (n^{1/n})^2.$ I take as knows that $n^{1/n} \to 1.$ Hence the last term $\to 1.$

Conclusion: $a_n/(n^2/e) \to 1.$ Therefore

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{a_{n+1}/[(n+1)^2/e]}{a_n/[n^2/e]}\frac{(n+1)^2/e}{n^2/e} \to \frac{1}{1} \cdot 1 = 1.$$

Answer (score 4):

If you already know and use Taylor series, there are some simple possible approches.

Considering $$a_n = \frac {(n^2-n)^{1+1/n}}{(1+\frac {1}{n})^\sqrt{n^2-n}}$$ as you did, $$\log(a_n)=\left(1+\frac 1n\right)\log(n^2-n)-\sqrt{n^2-n}\log\left(1+\frac 1n\right)$$ $$\log(a_n)=\left(1+\frac 1n\right)\left(2\log(n)+\log(1-\frac 1n)\right)-n\sqrt{1-\frac 1n}\log\left(1+\frac 1n\right)$$ Now, using the classical Taylor series, you could get $$\log(a_n)=\left(2 \log \left(n\right)-1\right)+\frac{2 \log
   \left(n\right)}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ So, limiting to the first order $$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=2\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=2\log\left(1+\frac{1}n\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)= \frac 2 n+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Now, using $x=e^{\log(x)}$ and Taylor again $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1+\frac 2 n+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Playing with my old pocket calculator $a_{10}\approx 57.1454$, $a_{11}\approx 67.7086$ which makes a ratio $\approx 1.18485$ while the Taylor expansion gives $1.2$. Similarly, $a_{100}\approx 4032.93$, $a_{101}\approx 4111.06$ which makes a ratio $\approx 1.01937$ while the Taylor expansion gives $1.02$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
L'Hospital's rule is not the alpha and omega of limits computation!

You can show  the log of the denominator tends to $1$, hence the denominator is equivalent to its limit $\mathrm e$. Here are some details:
\begin{align*}
\ln\biggl(\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^{\sqrt{n^2-n}}\biggr)&=\sqrt{n^2-n}\ln\Bigr(1+\frac1n\Bigr)\\&=\sqrt{1-\frac1n}\,n\,\ln\Bigr(1+\frac1n\Bigr)\\&=\sqrt{1-u}\,\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u},\quad\text{setting}\enspace u=\frac1n.
\end{align*}
As to the numerator, split it as
$$(n^2-n)^{1+1/n}=(n^2-n)\,n^{2/n}\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^{1/n}.$$
Now $n^2-n\sim_\infty n^2$ and the last two factors are equivalent to their limit $1$, hence
$$(n^2-n)^{1+1/n}\sim_\infty n^2,\enspace\text{so}\quad a_n\sim_\infty \frac{n^2}{\mathrm e}.$$

Comment: I followed what you said on the numerator, but I'm still having trouble with "You can show the log of the denominator tends to 1." Would you mind nudging me in the right direction?

Comment: @Gizmo: I've added some details.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this identity - If $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{1/n}=l.$ So you just havr to find the limit 
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}[{ \frac {(n^2-n)^{1+1/n}}{(1+\frac {1}{n})^\sqrt{(n^2-n)}}}]^{\frac {1}{n}}$$

So now just take ln both the sides and put $n=\frac {1}{t}$, so limit will change to $$lnL=\lim_{t\to\ 0}t[(1+t)ln(\frac{1-t}{t^2})-\frac{\sqrt{1-t}}{t}ln(1+t)]$$

Now, you can solve this limit very easily which is equal to zero. So

$$lnL=0$$ So $$L=1$$
Hence Proved

Comment: You have clearly stated in your first line that if $a_{n + 1}/a_{n} \to L$ then $a_{n}^{1/n} \to L$. But this does not mean that you can infer the limit of $a_{n + 1}/a_{n}$ from that of $a_{n}^{1/n}$. Your stated identity does not work in reverse. Thus your solution as it stands is wrong.

Comment: @paramanand May be, you didn't understand what i have done. We have to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$. Now for some time, assume this is true. Now, if this is true, then we can say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{1/n}=1$ which i have proved in my answer. So that means our assumption was absolutely correct. And also, can you prove it that why vice-versa is not true ?

Comment: Please don't take it otherwise but I have understood exactly what you have done. Your approach would work if we could somehow guarantee the existence of $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n + 1}/a_{n}$. And for counter example, let us define $a_{n}$ by $a_{2n} = 1/n^{2}, a_{2n - 1} = 1/n^{3}$ then $a_{n}^{1/n} \to 1$ and $a_{n + 1}/a_{n}$ does not have a limit.

Comment: i didn't understand your counter example. If $a_{2n}=\frac {1}{n^2}$, then $a_{2n-1}=\frac {4}{(2n-1)^2}$. But how did you assumed $a_{2n-1}=\frac {1}{n^3}$. Can you please explain this ? I think there is a problem in your counter example.

Comment: There is no issue in my counter example. The terms of the sequence are as follows: 1, 1, 1/8, 1/4, 1/27, 1/9, 1/64, 1/16,... The formula for $a_{n}$ depends on whether $n$ is odd or even. And that's why I have given two formulas for $a_{n}$ depending on the parity of $n$. Perhaps it would be better if I rewrite the same sequence as $a_{n} = 4/n^{2}$ if $n$ is even and $a_{n} = 8/(n + 1)^{3}$ if $n$ is odd.